# data exchange between boost::generic_image_library and external class

Tags: c++, image-processing, boost

I know how external class data can be transformed into generic image library class, such as the following codes show:

```
    unsigned char *dst_pixels;
    dst_pixels = new unsigned char [200*500];
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<200; j++)
            dst_pixels[i*200+j]= j;
    }
    gray8c_view_t my_view = interleaved_view(200,500,(const  gray8_pixel_t*)dst_pixels,src_row_bytes);
```

However, I cannot find a easy way to obtain the image data pointer in the image view class of generic image library, which can be used to communicate with external classes as the following codes show:

```
unsigend char *p_memory;
p_memory = my_view.get_pointers_to_the_image_data;
functin_work_on_p_memory;
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.